# RavenDB license expiration

Tags: ravendb

We are deploying an app for a lot of customers on different servers (Windows, Linux). Part of the app is a RavenDB instance which is always hosted on-premise next to the actual web app.

An activated RavenDB server states that the license expires at some time (Community edition in this case). It's no option to manually renew RavenDB licenses for all servers. What happens when the Community-license expires? And how is it possible to automate renewal?

Comment: https://ravendb.net/contact  ?

Answer (score 1):

Each RavenDB instance should have its own separate license and the renewal process cannot be automated.

Comment: Each instance already has it's own license. For automation: I do already know a workaround, but that's way too complicated (get license mail via SMTP API, scrape the key and write it to the license file). Was just wondering if there is an official/easier way.